# Minor ticks at density log plot in lattice (R)

Tags: r, lattice

I need to create a density plot using the lattice package of R. The x-axis has a logarithmic scale. Minimal example:

```
densityplot( ~ mpg, data=mtcars, scales=list(x=list(log=TRUE)))
```

[image]

Is it possible to put minor tick marks between the major ticks? In xyplot this is possible with `xscale.components=xscale.components.log10ticks`, but this does not work with densityplots or histograms.

Answer (score 0):

I found out that this needs

```
library("lattice")
library("latticeExtra")
```

Now `xscale.components=xscale.components.log10ticks` works (for all lattice plots I think). I did not know that the `latticeExtra` is needed.